# Materialize CSS Autocomplete Down Arrow Not Working

Tags: autocomplete, materialize

Here is my code. I tried to use default code but nothing work. In following i am fetching json from php and use it in autocomplete. dropdown is display but down arrow is not working.

I am using Materialize CSS Version 0.97.7

```
<div id="productEditor" class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">   
                        <!-- <input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="product_finder" id="product_finder" placeholder="Type Product To Add Or Update"> -->
                        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
                        <script>
                            var autofilldata="";
                            function autocomplete_fetch()
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "product_list.php",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function( data ) {
                                        console.log(data);
                                        autofilldata=data;
                                        setAutoFill();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            function setAutoFill()
                            {
                                $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
                                    data:autofilldata
                                });
                            }
                            $(document).ready(function($) {
                                autocomplete_fetch();   
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be problem with my javascript file. So i test it with Latest CDN(0.98.2) and it worked.

After working i thought to **test it with version of 0.97.7 but this time i used CDN for it not local file**

In **following version** i test the code but **down arrow is not working in autocomplete**.

0.97.7

0.97.8

0.98.0

Both 0.97.7 and 0.97.8 down arrow is not working in autocomplete. **But in 0.98.0 it works.**

So from now i decided to choose to use updated Framework. There will be always improvement in new version and in that version our question was solved.